# Simplifying Shapefile using ArcGIS Desktop or alternative?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, google-maps, simplify

I have a shapefile that contains neighborhood boundaries that I want to simplify. Right now I am thinking of converting the shapefile to Google maps KML so I can insert the boundaries into the map as an overlay but do not need the precision provided by the shapefile. How can I do this simplification?

I may have access to arcgis, although a method that does not require it is better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a non-ArcGIS method, you could try [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org) - the "Simplify Geometries" tool under the Vector menu should do what you want!

Comment: The Generalizer plugin is also good as you can use different algorithms, if needed of course.

Answer (score 3):

The [Simplify Polygon](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//007000000011000000) geoprocessing tool in ArcGIS can do this.  Things can get complicated with imperfect topology though.  So if your boundaries don't match up perfectly, you will want to use the FLAG_ERRORS or RESOLVE_ERRORS keywords in the error_option parameter.

Afterwards, you should have no trouble converting this to a KML for overlay purposes in Google Earth.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use this online service that does exactly that: http://mapshaper.org/ I have use it several times and works like a charm. I usually go for 0.09% when it comes about simple color graduated maps.