# How to simplify polygon shapefile and maintain topology?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, topology, simplify

I'm looking for a straightforward answer that actually works...not a 'duplicate question' flag. None of the other solutions posted in similar threads actually work...they all have dead-end answers and/or links. I've searched for hours and spent many more actually trying the methods I've found and none seem to work.

As for my question; I'm looking to generalize the polygons of a shapefile to reduce their resolution. Topology needs to be maintained for future geometry functions such as difference and union. There doesn't seem to be any way to preserve topology in QGIS...is there any other way? Any suggestions will help (as long as it doesn't involve ArcGIS).

Previous questions which don't have useful answers:

[Simplifying Shapefile using ArcGIS Desktop or alternative?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18109/simplify-shapefile) - topology is not considered

[Generalizing polygon file while maintaining topology in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20799/how-to-generalize-a-polygon-file-and-maintain-topology-in-qgis) - no accepted answer

[How to check Topology in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34415/how-to-check-topology-in-qgis)

Also another questions of mine:

[Simplify by number of points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85924/simplify-by-number-of-points-in-qgis)

Comment: It may help to add links to the questions/solutions you have already tried. This may help others to know what questions you have looked at and prevent them from flagging this as a duplicate.

Comment: Do you mean multi-layers topology or only self topology? I have a solution with FME for both but I think you can reproduce it with another chain of treatement such in postgis or even QGIS maybe.

Comment: Self-topology within a single shapefile (no gaps in between polygons, no overlapping polygons, etc.). If you have a set of steps for QGIS, I'd love to try it out. Also, what does FME stand for; is that another software package?

Comment: See if arcgis solution will point you in a right direction. 1.convert topologically correct polygons to polylines. 2 planarise lines. 3. Generalise lines. 4. Build polygons from simplified lines/edges. Don't forget to transfer original polygon attributes to point shapefile, so that you can bring them back

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", it would be useful to know what happened instead. That might help to understand what is different between your situation and the situation in those questions.

Comment: The solutions don't work period. They didn't work for their OPs or me...the topology simply isn't preserved. I guess I shouldn't say they didn't work...I should have said the answers weren't correct.

Comment: Please note that it does not improve the quality of this site to have two unanswered questions about the same issue. That's why I'm closing this as duplicate and putting a bounty on the older question to motivate answers.

Comment: Reasonable enough...the only reason I posted was to bump the topic for more attention. I'm sure the added bounty to the other question will help. Thanks.